# jquery load() is not loading my django view in another view

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

So i have got my html and i would like to add my django view in div "radio2".
I am using JQuery function Load() but i have a problem because it returns error 404 with get request "http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/afafa/%7B%" and its not loading nothing in div

***post_detail.html***

```
<div class="post__recommendation__posts">
        <div id="radio2" class="radio2">
        </div>
        {% for post in posts|slice:":3"  %}

        <div class="post__recommendation__post">
            <div class="post__recommendation__post-image">
                <img src={% static post.image.url %} alt="shakhur" />
            </div>
            <div class="post__recommendation__post-description">{{post.short_description}}</div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
```

***Js function***

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    console.log("Loading page")
    $(".radio-btn").click(function(){
        console.log("radio - btn")
        console.log($(this)[0].id)
        $.ajax({
            url: "/radio/",
            type: 'POST',
            data:{
                radio: "radio",
                input: $(this)[0].id
            },
            success: update_item()
        })
    })
})

function update_item() {
    $('#radio2').load(
        "{% url 'radio2' %}"
        
    ); 
}
```

**View**

```
@csrf_exempt
def radio_test(request):
    return render(request, 'blogapp/radio2.html')
```

***radio2.html***

```
<div class="radiodiv">
This is Radio2
</div>
```

[image]

my results in console

```
Not Found: /post/afafa/{%
[28/Sep/2020 15:52:19] "GET /post/afafa/%7B% HTTP/1.1" 404 3938
[28/Sep/2020 15:52:19] "POST /radio/ HTTP/1.1" 200 79
[28/Sep/2020 15:52:22] "GET /post/afafa/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10761
```

Comment: use event delegation model.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: You've got `"{% url 'radio2' %}"` in your javascript. Is the javascript inline in your html template?

Comment: Nope i am using <script src={% static 'js/dashboard.js' %} type="text/javascript"></script> in my main.html

Comment: So `"{% url 'radio2' %}"` is being processed literally. It's not being interpreted by Django's templating engine. You are literally passing `{% url 'radio2' %}` into `load`, not a real URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to use Django's templating engine in a static file.

This will not work because static files are not passed into the templating engine.

There are work-arounds. Easiest is to create a global variable in the main template and pass that into `load`:

```html
<script>
var radio2_url = "{% url 'radio2' %}";
</script>
```

Put this **before** your other script.

Then in your js:

```js
function update_item() {
    $('#radio2').load(radio2_url); 
}
```